# Access Swift instance variable from single serial queue results in Thread Sanitizer issue

Tags: swift, multithreading, metal

I've a `MTLBuffer` instance variable that I only access (read) from the serial queue associated with an `NSManagedObjectContext`.

I use a `MTLParallelRenderCommandEncoder` to split up my drawing work in a part that happens from the main thread and a part that happens on the `NSManagedObjectContext`'s serial queue.

Still I get a thread sanitiser issue (or crash inside Metal) when accessing this `MTLBuffer`. Why does this happen?

My code looks basically like:

```
final class Renderer: NSObject {
    private var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    private var geometryBuffer:MTLBuffer!

    init() {
        geometryBuffer=device.makeBuffer(length: 1024*1024, options: .storageModeShared)
    }

    func draw(with renderEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder) {
        moc.perform {
            renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.geometryBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0) //CRASH HERE (1)
            renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: self.geometryBuffer.length/(MemoryLayout<Float>.size*3)) //OR CRASH HERE (2)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: MTKViewDelegate {
    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let parallelRenderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeParallelRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { return }
        guard let layersRenderEncoder=parallelRenderCommandEncoder.makeRenderCommandEncoder() else { return }
        guard let renderEncoder = parallelRenderCommandEncoder.makeRenderCommandEncoder() else { return }

        renderer.draw(layersRenderEncoder) //This will dispatch to serial queue

        //Continue with the other renderEncoder
    }
}
```

With the thread sanitiser enabled the issue is catch'ed on (1) with the following stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007fff664f42de in __cxa_throw ()
#1  0x00007fff664e62e5 in std::__1::__throw_system_error(int, char const*) ()
#2  0x00007fff664a0acd in std::__1::mutex::lock() ()
#3  0x00007fff578cfbc2 in -[MTLToolsCommandBuffer addRetainedObject:] ()
#4  0x00007fff57930431 in -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setVertexBuffer:offset:atIndex:] ()
```

Without the thread sanitiser I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` on (2).

Is there some additional access to `MTLBuffer`'s aside from 'my' serial queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MTLParallelRenderCommandEncoder` requires that its `endEncoding` calls is made after all sub-encoders have finished.

This can be accomplished by using a `DispatchGroup`, as shown in the following updated code (`endEncoding` commands also added)

```
final class Renderer: NSObject {
    private var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    private var geometryBuffer:MTLBuffer!

    init() {
        geometryBuffer=device.makeBuffer(length: 1024*1024, options: .storageModeShared)
    }

    func draw(with renderEncoder: MTLRenderCommandEncoder, group: DispatchGroup) {
        group.enter()

        moc.perform {
            renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(self.geometryBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0) //CRASH HERE (1)
            renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: self.geometryBuffer.length/(MemoryLayout<Float>.size*3)) //OR CRASH HERE (2)

        renderEncoder.endEncoding
        group.leave()
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: MTKViewDelegate {
    var encodingGroup=DispatchGroup()

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let parallelRenderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeParallelRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor) else { return }
        guard let layersRenderEncoder=parallelRenderCommandEncoder.makeRenderCommandEncoder() else { return }
        guard let renderEncoder = parallelRenderCommandEncoder.makeRenderCommandEncoder() else { return }

        renderer.draw(layersRenderEncoder, group: encodingGroup) //This will dispatch to serial queue

        //Continue with the other renderEncoder
        /* Do some encoding work here */

        //Finish this encoder
        renderEncoder.endEncoding()

        //Wait for all encoding threads to finish
        encodingGroup.wait()

        //End final encoder
        parallelRenderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
    }
}
```